# Terraform and AWS Elastic Beanstalk integration

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, terraform-provider-aws

I am using a Terraform module to manage AWS Elastic Beanstalk applications and environments and I want to pass the info from my db (Postgres) to my application automatically. I'm new with Terraform and I have this question.

My application in py where I want it to receive the info from the db created through terraform without me having to put it manually:
#ebextensions .config

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    PYTHONPATH: "/var/app/current:$PYTHONPATH"
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: "server:app"

container_commands:
  01_initdb:
    command: "source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate && python3 database.py"
    leader_only: true
```

#database.py

```
if 'RDS_DB_NAME' in os.environ:
 DATABASE_URL = \
 'postgresql://{username}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{database}'.format(
 username=os.environ['RDS_USERNAME'],
 password=os.environ['RDS_PASSWORD'],
 host=os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
 port=os.environ['RDS_PORT'],
 database=os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
 endpoint=os.environ['API_ENDPOINT']
        )
```

#elastic_beanstalk.tf

```
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_application" "application" {
 name = "my-awesome-app"
}
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "environment" {
 name = "my-awesome-environment"
 application = aws_elastic_beanstalk_application.application.name
 solution_stack_name = "64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.4.0 running Python 3.8"

 setting {
 namespace = "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration"
 name = "IamInstanceProfile"
 value = "aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"
  }
}
```

#db.tf

```
provider "aws" {
  region = var.region
}

data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {}

module "vpc" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  version = "2.77.0"

  name                 = "helptech"
  cidr                 = "10.0.0.0/16"
  azs                  = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names
  public_subnets       = ["10.0.4.0/24", "10.0.5.0/24", "10.0.6.0/24"]
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
  enable_dns_support   = true
}

resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "helptech" {
  name       = "helptech"
  subnet_ids = module.vpc.public_subnets

  tags = {
    Name = "helptech"
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "rds" {
  name   = "helptech_rds"
  vpc_id = module.vpc.vpc_id

  ingress {
    from_port   = 5432
    to_port     = 5432
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 5432
    to_port     = 5432
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "helptech_rds"
  }
}

resource "aws_db_instance" "dbbanco" {
  allocated_storage      = 5
  engine                 = "postgres"
  engine_version         = "12.9"
  instance_class         = "db.t3.micro"
  identifier             = "dbtechmanhelp"
  username               = "postgres"
  password               = var.db_password
  db_subnet_group_name   = aws_db_subnet_group.helptech.name
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.rds.id]
  skip_final_snapshot    = true
}
```

#variables.tf

```
variable "region" {
  default     = "us-east-1"
  description = "AWS region"
}

variable "db_password" {
  description = "RDS root user password"
  sensitive   = true

}
```

#repo structure

```
|-- .ebxtensions
|   └-- 01_fastapi.config
|-- .elasticbeanstalk
|   └-- config.yml
|-- .github\workflows
|   └-- deploy-to-eb.yml
|-- infra\sqlalchemy
|   └-- models.py
|   └-- questions.py
|   └-- schemas.py
|-- Terraform
|   └-- backend.tf
|   └-- db.tf
|   └-- elastic_beanstalk.tf
|   └-- outputs.tf
|   └-- variables.tf
|-- .gitignore
|-- Procfile
|-- database.py
|-- server.py
└-- requirements.txt
```

Thanks and sorry for my English

Comment: Ok, it can probably be done. Where is the extensions file located?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the Python file.

Comment: You are in Environment variables @MarkoE

Comment: Please add any code you have to the question. Also: never commit your state file to the VCS, it stays in commit history forever. Plus your repo is public so anyone can now use it to work in your AWS account.

Comment: The last part is not true though: the state file was empty. So you are safe, but the other statements you should take seriously.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! This audience is not the one I am working with, it is a copy just to share and ask questions if needed @marko

Comment: I know, but bad habits die hard. :) Would you mind just updating the question with at least the repo structure, so how the folders and files are arranged there? I have a possible answer but I need to see how everything is organized.

Comment: No worries. :) If it's not too much to ask, can you add the db.tf and variables.tf files as well? I just need to see what's already there.

Comment: done! I put the missing ones!

Comment: The more I'm thinking about this the more I'm inclined to ask: do you have to use Beanstalk?

Comment: Not necessarily, I'm using Elastic more because it's a small project and I wanted to see if it has this possibility @MarkoE

Comment: Because I think some of the stuff can be done more easily with e.g., API Gateway + Lambda. You could easily get the DB connection string into the Python file, but it would be visible and there are sensitive information there. You could as well approach it by saving the sensitive information in Secrets Manager and then populating the Python file using that.

Comment: interesting, I initially thought the elastic would facilitate some paths but it seems it has some limitations @MarkoE

Comment: Well, what really makes me uncomfortable is the fact you would have the connection string in plain-text. Not sure if there is any way to provide the env variables to ElasticBeanstalk, but Lambda now has support for Secrets Manager: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/10/aws-parameters-secrets-lambda-extension/.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I will migrate to lambda and any questions I will ask again!